# The map $f:\bar{B}\to \bar{B}, $ continuous such that $ \bar{B}\subseteq C[0,1],$ unit closed, need not have a fixed point.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

The map $f:\bar{B}\to \bar{B}, $ continuous such that $ \bar{B}\subseteq C[0,1]$, need not have a fixed point.

Know about the Brouwer fixed point Theorem on $\mathbb{R}
^n$ which states that  if $ \bar{B}\subseteq \mathbb{R}
^n,$ closed and $f:\bar{B}\to \bar{B} $ is continuous, then there exists $x^*$ such that $f(x^*)=x^*.$

However, I sense that it's not true on $C[0,1]$ but I can't think of an example. Can anyone, please, provide an example? Thanks for your time!

Comment: What do you know about your set $B$?

Comment: Let $f(x) = x+c$ where $c$ is a non zero constant.

Comment: @TM Gallagher: It is closed.

Comment: And bounded and convex as well, no? Those are necessary conditions for the Brouwer fixed point theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ too

Comment: @Charles Madeline: The unit closed ball satisfies both properties.

Comment: Oh, is $B$ meant to be the closed unit ball?

Comment: @TM Gallagher: Yes, it is!

Comment: Oh ok $\bar{B}$ is the unit ball I see. Then considering Schauder's theorem (same conclusion as Brouwer, but on convex compact subsets of Banach spaces), what you want to know is why the unit ball in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is not compact. This is known as Riesz's lemma: unit closed balls are closed in normed vector space iff the dimension is finite. Does that help? (Of course you want an explicit counterexample so this does not answer completely the question)

Comment: @Charles Madeline: Yes, that's my worry!

Comment: What topology are you putting on $C[0,1]$? The answer to your question depends on this. Two trivial examples: If $C[0,1]$ is discrete then all $f$ are continuous, and finding one without a fixed point is trivial. If $C[0,1]$ is indiscrete, then only constant functions on it are continuous, and since their constant values are among their inputs, those values are fixed points.